# Greasemonkey remove a var in div

Tags: greasemonkey

I'm trying to remove overflow:hidden or change it with :visible in this line:

```
<div style="width:75px;height:95px;padding:7px;overflow:hidden;background:#fff;border:3px solid gray;border-radius:10px;">
```

I've tried with var overflow = visible; didn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Standard JavaScript, one div for simplicity:

```
document.querySelector('div[style*="overflow:hidden"]').style.overflow = 'visible';
```

jQuery, any number of divs, needs `@require` meta-property:

```
// ==UserScript==
.........................
// @require https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js
// ==/UserScript==

$('div[style*="overflow:hidden"]').css('overflow', 'visible');
```

Or simply use Stylish extension with the following CSS:

```css
div[style*="overflow:hidden"] { overflow:visible!important }
```